# Cannot use nameof in immediate window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a project which uses the nameof-operator and compiles fine:

```
var n = nameof(Main);
```

In my projects setting-->Build-->Output-->Advanced I set the language-version to C# latest major version (default).

However when I debug the code and paste the line into immediate window I get:

> The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context:

[image]

Does immediate use another language-version?

I am using vs2017 enterprise 15.9.8.

Comment: Which visual studio version are you using?

Comment: can you provide a minimal, yet more elaborate, example?

Comment: @GaganDeep vs2017 as of the tag. The enterprise-edition, if that´s what you were asking.

Comment: While debugging in Visual Studio 15.9.7, I can put `?nameof(result)` and get "result" in the Immediate Window. Show your exact Visual Studio version and perhaps a screenshot of your IDE when this happens.

Comment: @CodeCaster Updated question. Putting `?` infront didn´t change anything.

Comment: Isn't `nameof` a compiler feature rather than a run-time feature? It just creates a string out of a language symbol as far as I know.

Comment: @Dandré Sure, but why shouldn´t a **compiler**-featuire doesn´t exist at runtime?

Comment: Because it doesn't make any sense for it to do so. Its a nice way to have more static analysis at compile time than for runtime. I don't see the need for it at runtime, especially since you have reflection at your disposal. I think what you are looking for is the C# interactive instead of the Immediate window.

Comment: `nameof(Main)` returns me "Main" in VS Professional 15.8.8

Comment: The debugger does not use a C# compiler to parse input and watches.  It is a fairly basic eval()-style expression parser.  Maybe they'll use Roslyn some day.  Not today.

Comment: @HansPassant Annoying, but answers the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Dandré I don´t get your point. Every compiler-feature is executed at runtime, even a simple `if`-statement needs to be executed at **runtime**, even though it´s a language-feature.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, `if` is not a compiler feature. It is an instruction. `nameof` is not an instruction, it is a feature which the compiler provides as a way of convenience to the developer so that the developer doesn't have to use strings themselves to refer to language symbols such as variable names, etc. It should have no run-time significance.

Comment: @Dandré okay, but wouldn´t that also apply for other features such as `typeof` which is compiler-magic as well? Anyway the point stays the same: every statement is executed at **runtime**.

Comment: @HimBromBeere. Actually, `typeof` does emit only the Class described within the parentheses even though it also invokes a run-time handle afterwards. But `typeof` itself is also not run-time based. Look at the link below. It contains C# code that gets converted into IL (what a C# compiler would generate).
https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgBgATIIwG4CwAUMgMyYBM6AwugN6HoOanIAs6AslgBQCUt9jQQDcAhgCd0I9AF50AIjkA6AOIBTYABUAngAdVvfAUEBfAQzNNMbdmV78jgxqIkAjGemC7VAewBmXAGVgMTAAOwBzHkMTCwsSKw5iOzoHBgBIZ3QAY3dQkQBbH39KKItTAmMgA=

Comment: It can be confusing but let's be specific between language features and compiled code. So `Linq` (written in SQL form) gets compiled into extension methods behind the scenes. Even the `dynamic` keyword has some libraries being executed behind the scenes with your method (that you want to call) being specified as a string. The difference is that you can use that `Linq` and `dynamic` code at run-time because the language run-time has made provision for that. `nameof` is something that doesn't execute any instructions behind the scenes. The compiler emits the name of the symbol you want to use.